# How can I deal with "Error:missing closing quote"

Tags: python, c, pycuda

when I run this example of pycuda , a kernel part of which can run in C interpreter correctly:

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

mod = SourceModule("""

#include<stdio.h>

__global__ void say_hi(){
    printf("I am %dth thread in : \
            threadIdx.x:%d, threadIdx.y:%d,\
            blockIdx.x:%d, blockIdx.y:%d,\
            blockDim.x:%d, blockDim.y:%d.\n",
            (threadIdx.x+threadIdx.y*blockDim.x+ \
                (blockIdx.x*blockDim.x*blockDim.y)+ \
                (blockIdx.y*blockDim.x*blockDim.y)),
            threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y,
            blockIdx.x, blockIdx.y,
            blockDim.x, blockDim.y);
    }
""")

func = mod.get_function("say_hi")
func(block=(4, 4, 4), grid=(2, 2, 1))
```

but errors show up:

```
pycuda.driver.CompileError: nvcc compilation of C:\xxx\Local\Temp\tmpqfqdmr3f\kernel.cu failed
[command: nvcc --cubin -arch sm_75 -m64 -Id:\xxx\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pycuda\cuda kernel.cu]
[stdout:
kernel.cu(6): error: missing closing quote

kernel.cu(7): error: missing closing quote

2 errors detected in the compilation of "kernel.cu".
kernel.cu
]
```

is it something wrong with my compiler？
plz help if anyone have ideas(Sorry for the long question)

Comment: Maybe nvcc doesn't like continuation lines? Try writing the string in a lingle long line just to see if this is the issue. Maybe the triple double quotes?

Comment: thanks for help, I've tried so but sadly it doesn't work.

Comment: it shows that my python doesn't support more than 120 characters and triple double quotes is needed for the use of SourceModule. Maybe this error has something to do with like UTF-8 ?

Comment: Try with a simple source module, e.g. `printf("hello world");`

Comment: C doesn't allow literal newlines in a quoted string. But you are perfectly allowed to paste together one long string from shorter strings; `printf("hello" " world" "!");` where the whitespace between the quoted string fragments can contain newlines and other arbitrary whitespace.

Comment: seems like hello world works and it prints successfully after  removing '\n' marks. and I'm trying to fix my old codes now. tks a lot.